# How to access the OCC v2 hybris REST API

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on hybris-commerce-suite-5.5.1.2 Using REST API v2, I want to get all Delivery-modes from below web service https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/electronics/users/john.doe@mail.com/carts/00012001/deliverymodes Method: GET

Header: 
Authorization: bearer 36a0bd92-44b6-41ad-b471-f8f274cb62c8

User email id and cart code is already set in this web-service. Impex data already set for store. But it returns empty JSON like that {}.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set delivery address for that cart id, then only you will get delivery modes like

1. premium delivery
2. standard delivery and so on...